# Make thinkpad Fingerprint login more tolerant

Tags: fingerprint-reader

The fingerprint sensor on my thinkpad T14s is not very tolerant, it usually require 3-4 attempt before I can login with it.

It there a software trick to make it more sensitive/acceptive/tolerant, aka more likely to accept a login. ?

ENV: ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Try registering the same finger as another finger.

Comment: Considering how there are only eight types of fingerprints, changing the sensitivity of the sensor to be more lenient towards error may make the thing useless. Registering the same finger multiple times is generally the best way to handle situations where alignment or skin coverage may result in a failed match 

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if that is possible.

Tip:

Look for distinct features on your fingertip(s) and 'learn' the scanner to recognize these specifically.
I'd expect that to be more reliable.